# Is Klingon version of Google consistent with Star Trek canon?

Tags: star-trek

There's a Klingon version of Google in existence: https://www.google.com/?hl=xx-klingon

It doesn't translate all words, but if I talk only about translated words, are they in accordance with Star Trek canon?

Comment: Which Klingon canon? The one from the films/TV or the one that Mark Okrand invented? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_language

Comment: @Valorum Mark Okrand's dictionary is actually official and CBS owns its copyright.

Comment: They own the copyright to the dictionary, its format and sentence-examples, but not to the language and individual words. The language consists of two elements; The bits seen on screen (contemptuously referred to by speakers of Klingon as Paramount-Klingon) and the bits invented by Mark Okrand (supposedly the true Klingon language). It would be helpful for you to specify which you mean since they aren't the same thing.

Comment: @Valorum How about one answers with both in mind? Canon inconsistency based answers are popular here. e.g. Superman silver age, golden age etc.

Comment: That's certainly possible but I was hoping that OP would just explain which he means

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Klingon translation of of Google is consistent with tlhIngan Hol, the Klingon language invented by Marc Okrand. This includes:

1. Elements first heard in Star Trek films/series (Star Trek canon).
2. Elements first revealed through other licensed Star Trek sources, such as books and games (Star Trek "beta canon" or "soft canon").
3. Elements revealed by Marc Okrand through other channels (not Star Trek canon, but still part of the "Okrandian canon" that Klingon-speakers abide by).

Looking at the front page, we can find examples of each of these categories.

1. The phrase **De' DamaSbogh** ("data which you prefer", or "Settings"). The word **De'** ("data, information") was used in the first Klingon line in *Star Trek III: The Search for Spock* - [**qa'vam De' vIje' rIntaH.**](https://youtu.be/ksbxo6Ft4ho?t=24) ("I have purchased the Genesis data."). It also uses the verb prefix **Da**- ("you -> her/him/it/them"), which was first used in the sentence **vaj Daleghpu'.** ("Then you've seen it."), about a minute later in the same film.
2. The same sentence also contains the verb **maS** ("prefer") and the suffix -**bogh** (relative clause marker; "that which ..., the one that ..."), which were first revealed in *The Klingon Dictionary* (1st edition). -**bogh** has definitely been on-screen in later Star Trek works, such as *Star Trek V: The Final Frontier*, where Klaa says **muSuvbogh DoS vIpoQ.** ("I need a target that fights back."), but I don't know if the verb **maS** has.
3. The word **mIlloghmey** is used for "Images". **mIlloghmey** is the plural form of **mIllogh**, a word which was first revealed by Marc Okrand in [a message](http://klingonska.org/canon/2010-12-25-email.txt) dated November 15th, 2010. It has definitely been used in licensed Star Trek works since then (such as [*Talk Now! Learn Klingon*](http://www.startrek.com/article/learn-klingon-with-talk-now-cd-rom), where "camera" is translated as **mIllogh qonwI'**), but I'm not sure if it has ever appeared on-screen.

Finally, the phrase **Google bopbogh De'** ("information about Google") contains elements belonging to all three categories:

1. **De'** - revealed in *Star Trek III*
2. -**bogh** - revealed in *The Klingon Dictionary*
3. **bop** - revealed during [a game of Hokey Pokey](http://klingonska.org/canon/2005-07-27a-email.txt) back in 2005